# Find the expected number of two consecutive 1's in a random binary string

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A computer randomly generates a binary string of 65 bits, a mix of 0's and 1's. The question is, how to find the expected number of two consecutive 1's? For example, 110111 has 3 occurrence, and 010110 has 1 occurrence.

I did some research but still was unable to think through. When I saw the word 'expect', my first though was about Bernoulli distribution.

[How to calculate the expected value of number of two consecutive zeros in a randomly-generated binary string?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511289/how-to-calculate-the-expected-value-of-number-of-two-consecutive-zeros-in-a-rand)

The site above was the one that I tried to understand and kind of understood it, but the case was different, so I am still confused right now.

Thank you very much for helping me :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that *expectation is linear*. Now, you have $n=65$ (independent) bits $x_1,\dots,x_n$, that you can use to get $n-1=64$ different random variables $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$: $X_i$ is equal to $1$ if $(x_i,x_{i+1}) = (1,1)$, and zero otherwise.

- Step 1: show that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{4}$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$ (using the fact that $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ **are** independent (uniformly) random bits);
- Step 2: it is true that the $X_i$'s are **not** independent. But as stated upfront, [the expectation is a linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), and does not require independence:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}\left[X_i \right]
  $$
  even though the $X_i$'s are not independent.

Can you conclude?

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response! It will take me a while to fully comprehand :D

Comment: @BonnieLöwe Without all the fancy words: if both $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ exist, then no matter how correlated $X$ and $Y$ are you always have $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try working inductively. Solve the problem for $n$ bits, using the fact that when you append a bit to the end of a string, you are only increasing the number of pairs of $2$'s if the bit is a $1$ and if the string ends in a $1$

Answer (score 0):

Another hint. There are 64 pairs of bits in a 65 bit string, and for each pair the probability of 11 is ...

Comment: "There are 64 pairs of **consecutive** bits in a 65 bit string"

Comment: @ClementC. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of two consecutive 1s in a random binary string is 25%.

Comment: A percentage isn't a "number".