# A more game related stats question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are an infinite amount of true-false questions. My goal is to get to 100 points.

A correct answer will give me 1 point, and if I have 2 questions correct in a row, the any correct questions that are proceded by  2 correct questions will give me an additional point. So it's like a winning streak. 
(Example: right, wrong, wrong, right, right, **right**, wrong. I receive 5 points)

A incorrect answer will have no penalty except ending the bonus streak.

The question is, if I completely guess all the questions, so 50%, how many questions do I **expect** to play in order to get to 100 points?

Thanks all!

Comment: @EHH Acutally, the original question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722306/find-the-expected-number-of-two-consecutive-1s-in-a-random-binary-string#1722319 and this question in the post is just something that I thought similar as the question in the link. I dont think I understand the independence between variables.

Comment: @EHH Sorry, I probably didnt do anything. I am just trying to understand the bits question in a more realistic way.. maybe the game question is easier to understand?

Comment: No it's fine, I was just wanting to know if you'd started and got stuck anywhere in particular. I'll have a think about the problem, not sure exactly how to solve it just now :)

Comment: @EHH ok thanks! Also, do you know what section this question may belong to in combinatoric?  For example, the laplace transform is in differential equation. Where is this kind of question in combinatoric? Because at the moment I have almost no clue how to solve, doing more research will definitely help! :D

Comment: I think this question is mainly just probability theory so maybe add a probability tag too.

Comment: Here is a start: The minimum number of questions for reaching $100$ points is $51$, as $2+(51-2)\cdot2=100$. The probability of doing it within $51$ questions is $\frac{1}{2^{51}}$. Now calculate the probability of doing it within $52,53,54$ and so on questions, then calculated the expectancy.

Comment: @BonnieLöwe The independence of the variables in your linked question is obvious. The outcoume of $X_i$ does not depend on the outcome of $X_{i-s}: P(X_i|X_{i-s})=P(X_i)$. $1\leq  s \leq i-1$

Comment: @callculus Thanks! Sorry for asking stupid question, I know the viarables are independent, but the points I receive is dependent with the consecutive correct questions. What to do to handle that?

Comment: @BonnieLöwe Because of the dependency of the variables this question is much more difficult. If someone has an idea she/he will post it.

Comment: @callculus isnt this problem similar with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722306/find-the-expected-number-of-two-consecutive-1s-in-a-random-binary-string#1722319 The two consecutive 1s count as +1 occurance, if I get another 1, I get +1 without the need of two 1s. And if I get a 0 after the two consecutive 1s, I will need two 1s to get a +1. Like a bonus streak too?

Comment: "if I have $2$ questions correct in a row, the following questions will give me an additional point if I am correct" -- do I understand correctly that any correct answer preceded by at least two correct answers is worth $2$ points? So e.g. "wrong, right, right, right, right, right, wrong" would be worth $5+3=8$ points?

Comment: @joriki yes, instruction unclear haha :D Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ the expected number of questions to play before getting $n$ points if you previously got $0$, $1$ or at least $2$ answers right, respectively. So the value you're looking for is $a_{100}$. Then we have the recurrence relations

\begin{align}
a_n&=1+\frac12(a_n+b_{n-1})\;,\\
b_n&=1+\frac12(a_n+c_{n-1})\;,\\
c_n&=1+\frac12(a_n+c_{n-2})\;.
\end{align}

Solving the first equation for $b_{n-1}$ yields $b_{n-1}=a_n-2$, which we can substitute into the second equation to obtain $a_{n+1}-2=1+\frac12(a_n+c_{n-1})$. Solving for $c_{n-1}$ yields $c_{n-1}=2a_{n+1}-a_n-6$, and then substituting into the third equation yields

$$
2a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-6=1+\frac12(a_n+2a_n-a_{n-1}-6)\;,
$$

or

$$
a_n-\frac12a_{n-1}-\frac34a_{n-2}+\frac14a_{n-3}-2=0\;.
$$

The *ansatz* $a_n=\mu n$ yields $\mu=\frac85$, and the characteristic equation $\lambda^3-\frac12\lambda^2-\frac34\lambda+\frac14=0$ has roots $1$ and $\lambda_\pm=(-1\pm\sqrt5)/4$ (with $|\lambda_\pm|\lt1$), so the solution has the general form

$$
a_n=\frac85n+c+c_+\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}4\right)^n+c_-\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt5}4\right)^n\;.
$$

Thus we have $a_{100}\approx160$, and you can get the exact value by finding $c$ and $c_\pm$ using the initial values $a_0=b_0=c_0=c_{-1}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will need some time to understand. But taking this chance, can you please just have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722306/find-the-expected-number-of-two-consecutive-1s-in-a-random-binary-string#1722319            If the question in this post is changed into: a total of 65 questions, the bonus streak starts after 1 correct answer instead of 2, and only the bonus from the consecutive correct answer counts toward the total points, and ask for how many points do you expect to get when all 65 questions are finished. Are they the same case then?

Comment: @BonnieLöwe: Yes, they are, but finding the expected number of points given the number of questions is a lot easier than finding the expected number of questions given the number of points.

Comment: ok thanks! What field of study do you think this question belong to? Like probability theory?

Comment: @BonnieLöwe: Yes, the question is about probability -- though the answer doesn't have much to do with probabilities, only in setting up the recurrence relations, and is more about solving the recurrence relations (for which there's also a tag here, in case you're interested: [tag:recurrence-relations]).

Comment: Can you also please explain a bit about the ansatz a_n = μn, μ=8/5, and the characteristic equation? Or where can I gather information on them? I searched on google and didnt seem to find a site. Thank you really so much!

Comment: @BonnieLöwe: This Wikipedia section is a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving. The *ansatz* suggested itself since one might expect the expected number of questions to be roughly proportional to the desired number of points; but don't worry if you wouldn't have come up with it; there are also systematic ways of solving nonhomogeneous linear recurrence relations; here, too, Wikipedia is a start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients.

Comment: ok I will put more time on recurrence relation. Thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: For each trial (starting at the third) the probability of being bonus eligible is the probability of being preceded by two successes $0.5^2 = 0.25$. So the score for the trial is $0$ with probability $0.5$, $1$ with probability $0.5(1-0.25)$, and $2$ with probability $0.5(0.25)$. The expected value of each trial is therefore $0.625$. So, a rough approximation is $100/0.625 = 160$ trials to reach $100$.

Comment: @A.Webb I think I understood yours, but can you please explain why the score of $1$ has a $0.5(1-0.25)$ probability instead of $0.5$ just like score of $0$? EDIT: Nvm I got it. Thanks :D

Comment: @BonnieLöwe It's the probability of the event of being successful in that trial _and not_ being bonus eligible in that trial.

Comment: @A.Webb yeah, thanks!